# Need some help find Open Reading frame in DNA using Regex?

Tags: python, regex, eclipse

I'm trying to find all the possible reading frames of a minimum nucleotide length.

```
"A[TU]G(?:(...){3}){%d,}?(?:[TU]AG|[TU]AA|[TU]GA)" % (minimal_aa)
```

this pretty much does what I want, but for some reason, some reading frames do not acknowledge some stop codons.

I'm sure it has something to do with the `(...)` portion. How do I tell it to ALWAYS stop at `[TU]AG|[TU]AA|[TU]GA`, although passing through multiple start codons is fine.

I'm using Python on Eclipse.

I'm using Pythex.org to check my strings, but here's a sample of what I'm talking about:

AUGGAGAGCCUUGUUCUUGGUGUCAACGAGAAAACACACGUCCAACUCAGUUUGCCUGUCCUUCAGGUUAGAGACGUGCUAGUGCGUGGCUUCGGGGACUCUGUGGAAGAGGCCCUAUCGGAGGCACGUGAACACCUCAAAAAUGGCACUUGUGGUCUAGUAGAGCUGGAAAAAGGCGUACUGCCCCAGCUUGAACAGCCCUAUGUGUUCAUUAAACGUUCUGAUGCCUUAAGCACCAAUCACGGCCACAAGGUCGUUGAGCUGGUUGCAGAAAUGGACGGCAUUCAGUACGGUCGUAGCGGUAUAACACUGGGAGUACUCGUGCCACAUGUGGGCGAAACCCCAAUUGCAUACCGCAAUGUUCUUCUUCGUAAGAACGGUAAUAAGGGAGCCGGUGGUCAUAGCUAUGGCAUCGAUCUAAAGUCUUAUGACUUAGGUGACGAGCUUGGCACUGAUCCCAUUGAAGAUUAUGAACAAAACUGGAACACUAAGCAUGGCAGUGGUGCACUCCGUGAACUCACUCGUGAGCUCAAUGGAGGUGCAGUCACUCGCUAUGUCGACAACAAUUUCUGUGGCCCAGAUGGGUACCCUCUUGAUUGCAUCAAAGAUUUUCUCGCACGCGCGGGCAAGUCAAUGUGCACUCUUUCCGAACAACUUGAUUACAUCGAGUCGAAGAGAGGUGUCUACUGCUGCCGUGACCAUGAGCAUGAAAUUGCCUGGUUCACUGAGCGCUCUGAUAAGAGCUACGAGCACCAGACACCCUUCGAAAUUAAGAGUGCCAAGAAAUUUGACACUUUCAAAGGGGAAUGCCCAAAGUUUGUGUUUCCUCUUAACUCAAAAGUCAAAGUCAUUCAACCACGUGUUGAAAAGAAAAAGACUGAGGGUUUCAUGGGGCGUAUACGCUCUGUGUACCCUGUUGCAUCUCCACAGGAGUGUAACAAUAUGCACUUGUCUACCUUGAUGAAAUGUAAUCAUUGCGAUGAAGUUUCAUGGCAGACGUGCGACUUUCUGAAAGCCACUUGUGAACAUUGUGGCACUGAAAAUUUAGUUAUUGAAGGACCUACUACAUGUGGGUACCUACCUACUAAUGCUGUAGUGAAAAUGCCAUGUCCUGCCUGUCAAGACCCAGAGAUUGGACCUGAGCAUAGUGUUGCAGAUUAUCACAACCACUCAAACAUUGAAACUCGACUCCGCAAGGGAGGUAGGACUAGAUGUUUUGGAGGCUGUGUGUUUGCCUAUGUUGGCUGCUAUAAUAAGCGUGCCUACUGGGUUCCUCGUGCUAGUGCUGAUAUUGGCUCAGGCCAUACUGGCAUUAA

wait. this is a bad example. because it actually checks out right now that I eyeball the output. I had to shorten this, but there was one code a few thousands of nucleotides that was riddled with stop codons and nothing was working properly. I hope you get what I mean, if not don't worry.

Thanks in advance amigos!

Comment: Please also include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to supply some example inputs and outputs?

Answer (score 1):

Try with this pattern which find all the small and eventually overlapped sequences:

```
(?=A[TU]G((?:.{3})+?)[TU](?:AG|AA|GA))
```

You can find each sequence in capturing group 1 without start and stop codons.